# WebSocket In SYN_SENT State

Tags: firewall, proxy, tcp, websocket

Redirected from NE,

I have a problem in establishing a connection with using websocket.

[netstat console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJam.png)

FYI, the target that we wish to connect to is 10.121.244.17:45678 which is an instance of socket server. The problematic executable is covered in Red which let say represents ABC.exe.

As you can see in the console, both requests to connect with the socket server have been redirected to 116.206.196.77:3128 which I am not really convinced that it is a firewall.

This is because I have used puttyTel.exe to test the connection of the socket server and it did work which can be seen at the console output.

Besides, pinging to address of 116.206.196.77 returns request timed out.

Thus, is there any way i can know when is the SYN request being redirected to this address?

Comment: Please copy-paste output of commands instead of inserting images hosted on outside servers to the question. What does TCPDump / Wireshark show about the connection packets? BTW. It is SYN, not SYNC. Do you have some proxy settings enabled?

Comment: Hi @TeroKilkanen, I am sorry that i couldn't copy the output command as it is from a client's computer. I have just found out that the problem is due to proxy. Really appreciate your help.